# Why can't I get password type input content

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to write a user registration page. For foolproofing purposes I want users to repeat chosen password when filling forms. What I'm aiming for is to check to field in every key press, hence code below

```js
let x = document.getElementById('passwordField').value;
let y = document.getElementById('passwordField').innerText;
let z = document.getElementById('passwordField').textContent;
function check() {
    alert(x);
    alert(y);
    alert(z);
}
```

```html
<input type="password" name="passwordField" id="passwordField">
<br>
<input type="password" name="passwordRepeat" id="passwordRepeat" onkeypress="check()">
```

But for sake of my life I can' get first input field content for comparison.

What am I doing wrong? I would appreciate any help or any alternative method.

Comment: declare and initialize variables inside the function.

Comment: Welcome. Happy to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the value of the input field during runtime.  Currently you are storing the value from the input fields into variables which are more than likely either `null` or empty strings.

This should work.

```js
const passwordInput = document.getElementById('passwordField')

function check() {
alert(passwordInput.value)
}
```